# Why is my UI panel moved on remote client vs. original position on the host client

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am testing UNET and UI. When i place a panel in the scene it is OK in the host-client but the panel have another position on the remote client.

I am using the anchor points etc.

Can anyone please explain?

*Host-client*
[image: Host Client]

*Remote Client*
[image: Remote Client]

*Anchor Points*
[image]

Comment: Are the screen size of client and server the-same?

Comment: same thing when remote client is the Unity editor?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but still useful to answer.

There are 2 main possibilities. The simplest is that the canvas is not set up to adapt to screen resolution / window size properly. In this case, the remote vs client is a red herring and it's simply because you're authoring on one size, and then viewing on another. I like to set my canvas to "Scale With Screen Size" and to match height 100%, though it depends on your game.

The other potential which is a bit more insidious is that the UI panel's RectTransform is being modified by the server. This can happen when the panel has a NetworkBehaviour attached and the server and client run with a different screen size / resolution. The UI Canvas is actually an object that exists in 3D space. Its scale tends to seem a bit arbitrary and is set when the CanvasScaler adapts the UI to match the window. Any NetworkBehaviour objects are disabled when the scene is built and enabled when spawned by the server. This spawning process sets the **world** transforms to the values the server provides, but of course this is entirely dependent on the CanvasScaler on the server.

At the moment, spawned scene objects are enabled before their position, etc are set (I can't guarantee this will always be the case). Therefore, you can fix the problem by storing the RectTransform's **anchoredPosition** and **localScale** values in **Awake()**. You can then re-apply these in **OnStartClient()**. Alternatively, you can attach all network behaviours to the root canvas and not as a child object.

I hope that helps someone